# If $\gcd(A,B,C)=1$, can we find $h$ s.t. $\gcd(A,B+hC)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(A,B,C)=1$, can we find $h$ s.t. $\gcd(A,B+hC)=1$?

I have tried but I find I am not able to prove this. Maybe I do not know some important thing? Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: What does $\gcd(A,B,C)=1$ mean? That $\gcd(A,B) = \gcd(A,C) = \gcd(B,C) = 1$?

Comment: @graydad $\mathrm{gcd}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ is defined recursively as $$\mathrm{gcd}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=\mathrm{gcd}(\mathrm{gcd}(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}),a_n)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must check prime divisors $p$ of $A$:

for $p|A,C$ (and not $B$) every $h$ is fine,

for $p|A,B$ (and not $C$) we must have $h \equiv 1 \pmod p$,

for $p|A$ (and not B and C) we must have $h \equiv 1 -BC^{-1} \pmod p$, that is fine since $C$ is invertible in this case.

Put everything in a big Chinese Remainder System, you know you can solve it!

E.G.:

$(A,B,C)=(30,14,35)$

we have $2,3,5|30$.

$5|A,C$ so no problem.

$2|A,B$ thus we can take $h \equiv 1 \pmod 2$

$3|A$ we can take $h \equiv 1 - 14 \cdot (-1) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

$h=3k$ with $k$ odd verifies all the $3$ requests, you can easily check that $gcd(A,B+hC)=1$ for every $h$ of this form. (They are not the only one).

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quite understand why this is relevant to Chinese Reminder System since I am totally new to elementary number theory, could you please explain more?

Comment: I added an E.G.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an elementary proof, but it's all I have.

$1 = \gcd(A,B,C) = \gcd(A,\gcd(B,C))$.

Let $g = \gcd(B,C)$. Then $\dfrac Bg$ and $\dfrac Cg$ are integers and
$\gcd \left( \dfrac Bg, \dfrac Cg \right) = 1$.

$\underline{\text{Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions:}}$

If a and b are relatively prime positive integers, then the 
      arithmetic progression a, a+b, a+2b, a+3b, ... contains
      infinitely many primes.

So the arithmetic progression $\dfrac Bg + n\dfrac Cg$ contains infinitely many prime numbers. So, for some $n, \dfrac Bg + n\dfrac Cg = p$ where $p$ is a prime number such that $\gcd(A,p) = 1$. Since, also, $\gcd(A,g) = 1$, then we must have
\begin{align}
  1 &= \gcd(A,gp) \\
    &= \gcd\left(A, g\left(\dfrac Bg + n\dfrac Cg\right) \right) \\
   &= \gcd(A, B + nC)
\end{align}